# Storage capacity for a magnetic swipe card

Tags: data-storage, magnetic-cards

Any idea regarding the usual storage capacity of a magnetic swipe card ( like the ones that are used in ATM's ) ?

(PS : Tried googling but didn't get anything satisfactory and point on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_stripe, it appears that the card is composed of three tracks (as previously mentioned by Pax), and Tracks 1 and 3 have a bit density of 210 bits/inch, while Track 2 has a bit density of 75 bits per inch.

If the strip is 3.25" long, then it can theoretically store 1607 bits, with 682 on each of Tracks 1 and 3, and 243 on Track 2.

Answer (score 4):

ISO 7813 specifies the layouts for track 1 and 2. Track 3 is covered by ISO 4909.

Track 2 is the one commonly used for banking.

See [ISO7813](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_7813) and [ISO4909](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=33583) for details. Sorry, no wikipedia for 4909, you'll have to buy the docs from ISO or your country's standards body.